# How to add iPhone XR Simulator and iPhone XR to the Size bar. Xcode 11.5?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I need to run my application on iPhone XR Simulator. 
How can I add this to the size bar?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window->Devices and Simulators, select simulators. On the bottom of the left menu select the "+" sign, and then choose the Xr simulator on Device Type field.